# Как выводить значение по умолчанию, если оно не найдено?

Tags: c#

Есть перечисление, по которому пользователь может искать предмет. Если пользователь в query впишет что-то другое, которого нет в перечислении -> ему должно найти предмет по Label. что-то вообще туплю.
property всегда будет равно первом итему в перечислении. Потом даже если description будет первым, то его Label перетрёт.

```
private enum AvailablePropertyList {
    Label, Description
};

    foreach (var property in Enum.GetNames(typeof(AvailablePropertyList)))
    {
        if (property != AvailablePropertyList.Label.ToString() ||
            property != AvailablePropertyList.Description.ToString())
        {
            filter.SearchBy = AvailablePropertyList.Label.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Как мне тогда логику сделать, что если введеного значения нет - вывести Label по умолчанию?

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно почитать, как работать с перечислениями в C#. Что же касается кода: вы в цикле перебираете `Enum.GetNames(typeof(AvailablePropertyList))`. В цикле `property` будет сначала равно `"Label"`, потом `"Description"`. Поэтому ваше утверждение `property всегда будет равно первом итему в перечислении` - ложное. Скорее всего, вы имели ввиду, что `filter.SearchBy` всегда будет равен значению `Label`. Верно?

Comment: Не понятно что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то вы перемудрили, и `query` о котором вы говорите нигде нет

```cs
Enum.TryParse<AvailablePropertyList>(query, out var property);
filter.SearchBy = property.ToString();
```

Вот и всё.

Как это работает: `out var property` присваивается значение по умолчанию, если оно не найдено, а значение по умолчанию - это `0` для перечисления, потому что оно неявно наследует тип `int`, а значению `0` соответствует первое значение перечисления, если оно не указано явно, а первое значение здесь - `Label`. То есть то что вам нужно.